# OracleJet- How to know when a view is ready?

Tags: knockout.js, oracle-jet

Is there anyway to know if the view is ready/finished rendering? Since oraclejet uses Knockout for data-binding, is this on Knockout'part?

My usecase would be:

- Load the website. Router point to "A" view and that view uses "A.js" via "ojModule" namepsace
  as model
- I would like to run some codes after "A" view has been fully rendered.

Answer (score 3):

You may use busycontext for this as shown in the function below. You can refer more in [BusyContext](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet202/jet/reference-jet/oj.ModuleBinding.ConventionMethods.html#handleBindingsApplied)

```
function refreshBusyContext() {
  self.pageBusyContext = oj.Context.getPageContext().getBusyContext();
  self.pageBusyContext.whenReady().then(function () {
    console.log('page load is done');
  });
}
```

I think you can also use lifecycle methods like [handleBindingsApplied()](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet202/jet/reference-jet/oj.ModuleBinding.ConventionMethods.html#handleBindingsApplied) as below

```
self.handleBindingsApplied = function(info) {
 // Executes after all the bindings applied and all jet components are ready in view
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use BusyContext, also, as another option, you can think of using template binding, [link](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), and use afterRender callback.